# SerializeEditData when having more then one jqGrid in one aspx

Tags: jqgrid

When I create more then one jqGrid (be able to edit each of them)
 I use SerializeEditData to custom the data before sending it to server, when it's a single
 grid  it's work fine,
 with many grids only the last SerializeEditData (of the last jqGrid) is fired,
 it's seems like overriden event registretion problem, is some one faced that ?
 any idea for alternative for SerializeEditData ?

```
for example:
$("#Grid_1").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
    {/*navGrid options*/},
    {/*edit options*/
        serializeEditData: function (postdata) {
                 }
    },
    {/*add options*/
        serializeEditData: function (postdata) {
            // your implementation of serializeEditData for add
        }
    },
    {/*del options*/},
    {/*search options*/}
);
$("#Grid_2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
    {/*navGrid options*/},
    {/*edit options*/
        serializeEditData: function (postdata) {
                 //this function is fired
                // when trying to send to server from both Grids                     }
    },
    {/*add options*/
        serializeEditData: function (postdata) {
            // your implementation of serializeEditData for add
        }
    },
    {/*del options*/},
    {/*search options*/}
 );
```